# Set jqGrid edit options via setGridParam()

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to set some event handlers for jqGrid's edit events after the grid has been initialized. Namely, I need to handle the `beforeShowForm` edit event. I have tried this using `setGridParam` but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
$('#mygrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    edit: {
        beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
            // handle event
        }
    }
});
```

jqGrid's [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) is less than informative as to how these options are supposed to be set. How am I supposed to set these after-the-fact? I am aware that you can set this via the second argument for `jqgrid()`. I just need to do this after it has been created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not so easy to change parameters of edit events because the parameters are saved in internal variable of `navGrid` function. So you should unbind the click event to the "Edit" button and bind the new one event which call [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) method with all new parameters which you need. The new parameters can include event handler like [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events).

The corresponding code can be about the following:

```
var grid=$("#list");      // your jqGrid (the <table> element)
var grid_id = grid[0].id; // id of the <table> element like "list"
$("#edit_"+grid_id).unbind('click'); // unbind original 'click' handle
$("#edit_"+grid_id).click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-state-disabled')) {
        var sr = grid[0].p.selrow;  // get id of selected row
        if (sr) {
            grid.jqGrid("editGridRow",sr,
                        { // here you should place all Edit parameters
                            beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
                                alert("In beforeShowForm()");
                            }
                        });
        } else {
            // display error message
            $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+grid_id,jqm:true});
            $("#jqg_alrt").focus();
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATED**: If you call somewhere [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) method directly and can not change the code you can make following

```
var grid=$("#list");      // your jqGrid (the <table> element)
var orgEditGridRow = grid.jqGrid.editGridRow; // save original function
$.jgrid.extend ({editGridRow : function(rowid, p){
    $.extend(p,
             { // modify some parameters of editGridRow
                 beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
                     alert("In new beforeShowForm()");
                 }
             });
    orgEditGridRow.call (this,rowid, p);
}});
```

Comment: This grid is created by other code and the edits are primarily done by double clicking the row. I take it this will not work in that case?

Comment: @jcm: Probably there are misunderstanding already in your question. The event handler `beforeShowForm` will be used only in case of form editing. Either you somewhere in your code call `editGridRow` function or you add "Edit" button in the pager with respect of `navGrid` function (for example with `$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager');`). If you have another situation, that the name of event handler should be **not** `beforeShowForm`. Could you explain more what kind of editing you use and how the code looks like?

Comment: `editGridRow()` is being called by another piece of code. It's not being  called from the pager bar. I need to override the `beforeShowForm` even for an external `editGridRow()` call. The grid is being created by another piece of code that I cannot change.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is a little late, but I ran into the same problem.  After looking at the jqGrid source, here is what I did:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, { beforeShowForm: function (frmmgr) {
    alert('insert code here');
}
});
```